# Populating a Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, tuples

I have a long list of nested tuples that I am iterating through and appending in a certain way such that an empty dictionary:

```
dict = {}
```

will be filled like this:

```
dict = {a: {b:1,5,9,2,3}, b: {c:7,4,5,6,2,4}, c: {b:3,13,2,4,2}... }
```

The iteration will check if a nested dictionary exists, and if so, then it will append the value, otherwise, create a nested dictionary.  My poor attempt looks something like this:

```
longlist = [(1,(a,b)),(2,(b,c)), (3,(c,b)) ... ]
dict = {}
    for each in longlist:
        if dict[each[1][0]][each[1][1]]:
            dict[each[1][0]][each[1][1]].append(each[0])
        else:
            dict[each[1][0]] = {}
            dict[each[1][0]][each[1][1]] = each[0]
```

The problem with my approach is that the iteration fails because the dictionary is empty to begin with or that the parent of the nest doesn't exist in dict.  It's getting complicated for me.  I wasn't able to find much info online on how to tackle nested dictionaries, so I thought it should be okay to ask here.

Comment: `dict = {a: {b:1,5,9,2,3}, b: {c:7,4,5,6,2,4}, c: {b:3,13,2,4,2}... }`: Can you clarify how this is formed from something like this: `[(1,(a,b)),(2,(b,c)), (3,(c,b))]`? If you can clear that I can help with a solution.

Comment: taking a look at `(1,(a,b))`, the iteration will create `a:{}` and `b:{}`, which becomes `a:{b:{}}`.  This will then be append with 1, resulting in `a:{b:{1}}`.  The procedure repeats as the numeric values populate.  I placed a nonsequential numbers in the example because that's how the real world version ends up, I am working with hundreds of data :/

Comment: @JosephKim Added a further improvement. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution using `collections.defaultdict`

```
import random
import collections
choices = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

longlist = []
for i in range(1, 101):
    longlist.append((i, tuple(random.sample(choices, 2))))

print longlist

final = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(list))

for value, (key1, key2) in longlist:
    final[key1][key2].append(value)


print final
```

In general, the way that I would change your code would be to first ensure the nested dictionaries exist (collections.defaultdict takes care of this for you) and then always append once.

Something like

```
for value (key1, key2) in longlist:
    if not your_dict.get(key1):
        your_dict[key1] = {}
    if not your_dict.get(key1).get(key2):
        your_dict[key1][key2] = []
    your_dict[key1][key2].append(value)
```

Also not the for line vs "for each ..."  This is unpacking the items in the iterable.  You could also have done

```
for value, keys in longlist:
```

but since keys is an iterable as well, you can unpack it as well if you wrap it in parens.

Comment: I found that collections.defaultdict is actually a better way to check for existing dictionaries.  With a bit of tweaking, I was actually able to account for longer version of the longlist: `longlist = [(1,(a,b,d,e,...)),(2,(b,c,a,f,...)), (3,(c,b,a,f,...)) ... ]`

Answer (score 2):

Without delving much into what you are trying to do, you can rewrite your `if` statement to *not* throw an error if the keys do not exist:

```
if dict_.get(each[1][0], {}).get(each[1][1], None):
    dict_[each[1][0]][each[1][1]].append(each[0])
```

The `dict.get` is an extremely useful function in that it returns a certain default value if the given key does not exist.

Also, it seems you expect a list to exist. In the `else` block, did you mean to do this?

```
dict_[each[1][0]][each[1][1]] = [each[0]]
```

This will create a list with a single element, so now `dict[...][...].append(...)` will work.

I also recommend not using `dict` to name your variable. It shadows the inbuilt class.

Further improvements might include unpacking items in the head of the for loop, so you don't have to do `each[0]`, `each[1]`, and so on. You could use something like:

```
for idx, pair in longlist:
    x, y = pair # unpack each pair now
    ...
```

---

Full listing:

```
dict_ = {}
for idx, pair in longlist:
    x, y = pair
    if dict_.get(x, {}).get(y, None):
        dict_[x][y].append(idx)

    else:
        dict_[x] = {y : [idx] }
```

This is much more readable than before.

Comment: This worked out nicely.  The get function was what I was looking for.  I have accepted this as my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @JosephKim Glad I could help. Cheers!