# What exactly does the type lambda do when used with defaultdict

Tags: python

I remember this example

```
from collections import defaultdict
d_int = defaultdict(int, a=10, b=12, c=13)
d_int.default_factory = lambda: 1
d_int['d']
1
```

When we pass an unknown key it returns the default value instead of error,I understand this.
But in this SO question,[populating a nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45646576/populating-a-nested-dictionary) thing get more complicated.

```
final = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(list))
```

What does lambda type do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of default dictionary would be useful for 2 levels of data. Something like this:

```
{ k11 : { k21 : [...], k22 : [...] }, k12 : { ... } }
```

Here, each dictionary is `defaultdict`.

The `lambda` returns a `defaultdict` for the second level, when the first level key does not exist:

```
In [234]: final['k11'] # first level access
Out[234]: defaultdict(list, {})

In [235]: final['k11']['k21']  # second level access
Out[235]: []
```

Answer (score 2):

`defaultdict` needs a *function* (the factory).

In the second case, you need to create a `collections.defaultdict(list)`. For that you need a function, and it's simpler to define this function inline with a lambda that generates a new `collections.defaultdict(list)` object.